# WoW - How to sell bound bags/pouches

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How can I sell a bag/pouch that I previously equipped?
I bought a new bag and want to equip it, but can't because my bagspace is full.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When replacing bags, it works best if the bag you want to replace is completely empty -- then it's simply a matter of dragging the new bag to the place on your inventory pane. The equipped bag and the newly bought bag should switch spaces.

I believe you can also simply drag the old bag into a bank bag slot, leaving the space in *your* inventory empty, after which you can simply drag the new bag into the empty space.

Answer (score 7):

Blizz have quite nicely made this even easier.  Simply drag your new bag on top of the bag you want to replace and if it's larger then the contents will simply be swapped over automatically.  Easy :)